# Timestamp of DB queries within a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, transactions

I'm using `DB::transaction` and `SoftDeletes`.

For those unfamiliar with Laravel the `SoftDelete` functionality of Laravel abstracts away the setting / querying of rows in the database. When a record is deleted the field `deleted_at` is given a timestamp otherwise this field is `null`. This field is then used on querying to only get non deleted rows.

Currently I have a script that runs every day that deletes all the **soft deleted** entries that are older than 7 days.

[image]
This is where my question/problem is. What if my DB::transaction spanned for let's say 10 seconds and add the end writes to **Table A** and **Table B** so that the entries in both tables have a different timestamp.

I can picture a scenario where when the cleanup script executes it could delete HALF of the entry records.

**My question then is**

1. would a DB::transaction give the same timestamp to all the records?
2. if not how can I remedy this problem?

Comment: but the soft delete sets up later action by a garbage collector, no? any residue that isn't active is never reinstated is it? next time thru it gets wiped?

Comment: Not exactly because we let things get restored for up to 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can seeing it working, as it seems mission critical that your data isn't messed up with a partial restore as you say, is to include a transaction number in your affected tables.

The cleanup routine would need to be tweaked. A transaction cannot be `soft deleted` **and** subsequently wiped unless all the timestamps in the transaction exceed 7 days.

Comment: Thanks Drew that seems doable however does that confirm that db transactions to not ensure the same timestamp record on insertion?

Comment: I would never make the assumption about timestamp equality inside a transaction. I would expect them to be different.

Comment: I know how to make them the same if I had to, but you are inside an ORM.